# Django Form Validation Conflict

Tags: django, forms, validation, model

Something weird is happening. Lets say I have a field defined as:

```
Project_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

So `Project_name` must have a unique value otherwise it'll throw an error. Then I want to add other Validation checking. So in my `forms.py`

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    if data['team_member2'] == data['team_member3']:
        raise ValidationError("Can't have duplicate team members")
```

However, once I add this function in, the `unique` operator stops working for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `clean` method of super class while overriding.

Try this:

```
def clean(self):
    data =  super(FormClass, self).clean()
    if data['team_member2'] == data['team_member3']:
        raise ValidationError("Can't have duplicate team members")
    return data
```

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other):

> The call to **super(ContactForm, self).clean()** in the example code ensures that any validation logic in parent classes is maintained.

Comment: Holy! It worked, can you please tell me the logic behind this?

Comment: @AndyXu I've added a link to Django documentation which covers the issue in detail..